# What's wrong with my If-statement to check uploaded file? (PHP)

Tags: php

I am trying to test if the uploaded file is the image type I want. If it isn't a gif,jpeg, png, it should echo "Problem". But when I execute this code, it always says there's a problem. What's wrong with my if statement?

```
$uploadfile_type=$_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    if ( ($uploadfile_type !='image/gif') || ($uploadfile_type !='image/jpeg') 
    || ($uploadfile_type !='image/png'))  
    {
        echo 'Problem: file is not a gif or jpeg or png!';
        exit;
    }
```

This code works when I am only checking one type of image. Ex: if($uploadfile_type !='image/gif') --> this statement would work but when I add a OR it doesn't.

Comment: What does `$uploadfile_type` contain, and where is it set?

Comment: @ frank. $uploadfile_type=$_FILES['userfile']['type'];

Comment: The `$_FILES['blah']['type']` parameter is set by the... wait a second, this is the exact same question as 2472304: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472304/if-else-isnt-working-properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using OR (`||`) when you should be using AND (`&&`). You want to say there's a problem if it's not a GIF *and* it's not a JPG *and* it's not a PNG. With OR, the only way it wouldn't say there was a problem is if you had some sort of file that managed to be all 3 types at once.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Works now.

But why would it be wrong to say "if the image isn't a gif OR the image isn't a jpg OR the image isn't a png"?

If it was "and", why won't it be saying "it has to be a gif and a jpg and a png?

Sorry, for these simple questions--i'm new

Comment: Your code says : we should print an error when the image is a gif or when the image is a jpeg or when the image is a png. In other words : print an error whatever the type of the image !

Comment: @ggfan: It just requires a different way of thinking about it. The code was saying, "print an error if any of the following are true: it isn't a GIF, it isn't a JPG, it isn't a PNG". What you have to realize though, is that even if your image is a GIF, it also isn't a JPG and it isn't a PNG. So two of the conditions are still triggered, even in a "good" case.

Answer (score 2):

There's a riddle that goes:

> I have two coins in my pocket.  Their
>   total value is thirty cents.  One of
>   them is not a nickel.  What are they?

The answer is that they are a quarter and a nickel - the quarter satisfies the condition that "one of them is not a nickel".  This is the kind of problem you are facing.  *Every* file is `not a gif` or is `not a jpeg` - even the gifs and jpegs.  The gifs are `not jpegs`, and the jpegs are `not gifs`.  So, as others have said, you need to use `AND` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a list of accepted mimetypes :

```
$accepted_types = array(
    'image/gif',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
);

$uploadfile_type=$_FILES['userfile']['type'];

if (!in_array($uploadfile_type, $accepted_types))
{
    echo 'Problem: file is not a gif or jpeg or png!';
    exit;
}
```

I hope this will help,
Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AND instead of OR:

```
if ( ($uploadfile_type !='image/gif') && ($uploadfile_type !='image/jpeg')
  && ($uploadfile_type !='image/png'))
```

OR will always fail since a file will only ever be of a single type.

Answer (score 0):

Chad's answer is right.

If you want to shorten the code and make it prettier:

```
if (!in_array($uploadfile_type, array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'))
{
  // bad
}
```